# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'

Tags: django, pyrogram

Trying to call app.add_chat_members from Pyrogram in a Django view but can't seem to instantiate the client.

Steps to Reproduce
views.py

```
...
from pyrogram import Client

def add_users_to_chat(chat_id, user_ids, forward_limit = 0):
    user_bot = Client("session_name", api_key=API_KEY, api_hash=API_HASH)
    with user_bot:
        return user_bot.add_chat_members(chat_id, user_ids, forward_limit)

def add_user_to_chat_view(request):
    ...
    add_users_to_chat(request.kwargs.get('chat_id'),request.user.telegram_id)
```

I am running django in asgi with uvicorn `uvicorn config.asgi:application --host 127.0.0.1 --reload`.
I have tried using async:

```
async def add_users_to_chat(chat_id, user_ids, forward_limit = 0):
    user_bot = Client("session_name")
    async with user_bot:
        return await user_bot.add_chat_members(chat_id, user_ids, forward_limit)
```

I have also tried async_to_sync

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
@async_to_sync
async def add_users_to_chat(chat_id, user_ids, forward_limit = 0):
    user_bot = Client("session_name")
    async with user_bot:
        return await user_bot.add_chat_members(chat_id, user_ids, forward_limit)
```

Traceback

```
  File "/utils/telegram.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyrogram import Client
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pyrogram.methods import Methods
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .messages import Messages
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/messages/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .edit_inline_media import EditInlineMedia
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/messages/edit_inline_media.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .inline_session import get_session
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/messages/inline_session.py", line 27, in <module>
    lock = Lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/locks.py", line 164, in __init__
    self._loop = events.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

Comment: Hi @Joshua did you manage to solve it. Iam facing the same issue in 2021?